# Returning an integer and array from a function

Tags: c, arrays, dynamic

I need to write a function that lets the user input the number of integers (`n`) in the array (`A[n]`) and the array itself, but I'm not sure how I should return both of them from the same function.

Comment: Use pointer arguments

Comment: C had no references. But it has pointers ...

Answer (score 0):

You could basically return a `struct` with one member as array of integers and another `int` giving number of elements in array .